# Lamport-Diffie + Security Proof

Tags: hash-signature

I am studying Lamport-Diffie signature scheme. In the [lecture](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/crypto/f02/lectures/lecture36.pdf) present the algorithm  $A'$ for attempting to invert the one way function $f$, where $f$ is used to compute the public key. My question is Why to use this algorithm $A'$ to prove the Theorem 1?, Why I cann't use other any algorithm (for example Grover, or Brute Force)?

Comment: @xag please, Could you help me with this question?

Answer (score 3):

Well, $f$ is assumed to be a one-way function. That means, there cannot exist an efficient algorithm for finding preimages under $f$. The algorithm $A'$ is what we call a reduction.

We are trying to show that an efficient algorithm for attacking the signature scheme does not exist. To do that, we assume the contrary, i.e. we assume an efficient algorithm $A$ exists that successfully forges a signature. We then use this algorithm $A$ as blackbox (i.e. we do not assume anything about it beyond the fact that it works) to construct a second algorithm $A'$.
This algorithm can efficiently compute preimages under $f$, if $A$ works as specified. Because we assumed that $f$ is one-way, this a contradiction, as no such algorithm can exist if $f$ is one-way.

Now, because the existence of $A$ implies existence of $A'$, but $A'$ cannot exist, we can conclude that $A$ cannot exist either. This proves that no efficient adversary against the one-time signature scheme exists and the scheme is, therefore, secure.

Some algorithm for inverting $f$ that does not use the adversary against the signature scheme (besides not being efficient) would not allow you to conclude anything about the security of the scheme.

Comment: When you say "Some algorithm for inverting f that does not use the adversary against the signature scheme (besides not being efficient) would not allow you to conclude anything about the security of the scheme." Are you refer to Grover algorithm, for example ?. Which is a role of the classical and quantum algorithms to attempting invert $f$ in model attack CMA-secure?.

Comment: The goal of the theorem is to *show that algorithm A does not exist.* The way to this goal is constructed via A' and basic logic: $A \rightarrow A'$ and $A'$ is a contradiction to the original assumption. If you do not use A to construct A', then .... you have no statement about A.